# Fedora 27 sound output to a bluetooth device not working

Tags: fedora, audio, bluetooth, bluez

I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad T460 and a fresh installation of Fedora 27 with only a few Gnome Extensions and extra software installed. I got this laptop a few months now and only used Fedora (previously 26) with it. This problem existed the whole time (also similar bluetooth problems with my previous laptop [Lenovo Ideapad U410], with Ubuntu Gnome and also Fedora) and I thought I should try to reinstall the OS first and check if this was the problem.

I got a logitech bluetooth audio connector (this one) which is connected to my sound system. When I installed Fedora 27 I connected to this device and successfully listened to Spotify with this device. But after about half an hour it didn't work any more. Since then I tried it several times and got into one of the following situations:

- The os completely **froze**! When trying to connect to the device or
  turn on/off bluetooth. Only hard rebooting the notebook helped me then
- Connecting to the device works and I can listen a few minutes. Then suddenly playback stops and the device is still connected and
  recognized, but I can only listen to music/get sound through the
  notebook speakers
- Connecting to the device doesn't work at all
- Connecting to the device works, but it isn't recognized as a sound output device

So here I am with this nice laptop with built in bluetooth and it doesn't work which is not good. I have to admit that although I'm experienced with Linux and computers I don't know how to troubleshoot, find the problem or even fix this. I googled around and found this tutorial to manually pair bluetooth devices under Fedora over the CLI which I tried. Result:

```
[bluetooth]# devices
Device C8:84:47:08:5A:47 (47)Logitech Adapter
[bluetooth]# connect C8:84:47:08:5A:47 
Attempting to connect to C8:84:47:08:5A:47
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

As you can see the error message isn't helpful at all. So can anyone help me? What can I do to troubleshoot this? Where do I start? What can I check? (And yes, the Logitech device is working fine with my Android phone).

Here is some further information with lsusb and lspci:

```
[robert@thinkpad ~]$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04ca:7058 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

[robert@thinkpad ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor     Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev     21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card   Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

Comment: I find that running # disconnect C8:84:47:08:5A:47, after that org.bluez.Error.Failed error message usually fixes things.  If that doesn't help, try disconnecting, exiting bluetoothctl and running "pulseaudio -k".

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem with de comand line: pulseaudio -k

Comment: Pulseaudio usually fixes things if there's an audio driver crash, while possible, nothing in the OPs post suggests this is the case.

Comment: Usually disconnecting with bluetoothctl fixes the problem, but I have had some success on more than one occasion with resetting pulseaudio as suggested by Fagner Sutel.